# extracting xml schema from a set of tables

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to exract xml schema from a query.
Purpose is to persist the schema in sql db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within SQL Server, as far as I know - but you if you have your XML files in the file system, you can use the `xsd.exe` utility (or Visual Studio) to determine a possible XML schema based on the existing XML files.

See [MSDN docs on XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for how it works etc.

The result is just an approximation and not always perfect - but it's a start!